# An error of compile APK when i use Cocos2dx

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, apk, cocos2d-android

this new project can run in win32,but not compile APK,how can i solove it ?ths

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgw2T.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvQO4.png)

ps: i hava another question is i cann't find the error in the logs,where it is ?

Answer (score 0):

i find the error is the role of the  Android Package Name,i donn't know the first letter must be The English alphabet.